# update menuanchor of fullPage.js in R Shiny App from server side

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, fullpage.js, shinyjs

I am using the `fullPage` package to create a Shiny App and I am facing the following issue : I would like to update from the `server` side the labels of the menu that are first defined in the `pagePiling` function of the `ui` part.

I have seen in the HTML code that the field that I should update is the one here below, but I don't know how to change it/access it in the `server` part of my app.

```
<ul id="tocMenu">
        <li data-menuanchor="test_page">
          <a href="#test_page">temp_title</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I have the impression that this sould be achievable with javascript, but I don't know a lot about js ; among others, I have tried so far the following stuff :

```
library(fullPage)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
shinyApp(
  ui = pagePiling(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(), 
    center = TRUE,
    sections.color = c(
      "#CFE2F3"
    ),
    menu = c(
      "temp_title" = "test_page"
    ),
    pageSection(
      menu="test_page",
      pickerInput("title",  multiple = F, selected=NULL,
                  choices = c("Title 1", "Title 2")),
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$title, {
      # runjs("$('#fullpage').fullpage({
      #   anchors: ['test'],
      #   menu: '#tocMenu'});")
      runjs(paste0('document.getElementById("test_page").innerHTML = "', input$title, '";'))
    } ) 
  }
)
```

If anyone could help, I would be very grateful !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `getElementById()` but the menu title doesn't have an `id`, it has an `href` tag:

[image]

Therefore, you should use `querySelectorAll()` instead and specify the characteristics of the element you want to select (here, it's an element `a` that has `href="#test_page"`). Finally, this function returns a list of elements (this list only contains 1 element here), so you need to use `[0]` to select it.

Here's your example fixed:

```r
library(fullPage)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(
  ui = pagePiling(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(), 
    center = TRUE,
    sections.color = c(
      "#CFE2F3"
    ),
    menu = c(
      "temp_title" = "test_page"
    ),
    pageSection(
      menu="test_page",
      pickerInput("title",  multiple = F, selected=NULL,
                  choices = c("Title 1", "Title 2")),
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$title, {
      # runjs("$('#fullpage').fullpage({
      #   anchors: ['test'],
      #   menu: '#tocMenu'});")
      runjs(paste0('document.querySelectorAll("a[href=\'#test_page\']")[0].innerHTML = "', input$title, '";'))
    } ) 
  }
)
```